# Do ND filters affect contrast and dynamic range?

Tags: filters, contrast

I think I know what’s causing our confusion and miscommunication. Changing the ISO from a big number to double reduces the POTENTIAL Dynamic Range by about 1 stop. But it does not change the histogram displayed range. An ideal ND filter does not change the displayed range. Mine does significantly. Therefore it also changes the potential DR, OF THE SUBJECT, that can be captured without saturation. Not of the camera. Make sense?

What is the difference between decreasing contrast and increasing POTENTIAL dynamic range with an ND filter? Is it the same thing? Can I undo this effect in post? Can I cancel it out with the camera contrast setting? Can I get the same results with a pre or post setting instead of a filter?

The main purpose is to allow increased exposure time when the ISO is already minimized. I use this with Magic Lantern FPS override longer than 1/4 sec on a sunny day.

Here’s my theory. An ND filter loses data before it gets to the sensor. It compresses the brightness range giving less bits per pixel. With one exception. When there is too much dynamic range in your subject. It prevents over or under exposure when it’s impossible to shift the EV to capture both.

Obviously you have to change the exposure triangle so the average brightness is the same. Then you can compare contrast, with and without a filter for the same image.

I have an affordable ND filter. Does a quality filter also change the contrast? Does ND8 change sharpness more than ND2?

Thanks in advance I want to learn before I buy one.

Comment: Can we talk about sharpness? Is this only due to scattering light? It almost seems like scattering and sharpness are opposites. High DR and high contrast are mutually exclusive without changing cameras? Does an expensive ND8 keep sharpness?

Comment: I’m closing this question because it is discussion-oriented, and requires knowledge of conversations pertaining to other questions on Photo-SE. Questions should be standalone, and answerable more-or-less without requiring extended conversation. If possible, please edit it to be as self-contained, and less "meta" knowledge about conversations on this site. I.e., "I think I know what’s causing our confusion and miscommunication." **Whose** confusion? **Which miscommunication**? This implies site conversation, which is not suitable for questions on Main Photo-SE.

Comment: The confusing in the comments BELOW. I’m not allowed to update the question to reflect what we learned below? It is not referring to other questions. Come on you can do better Scott.

Comment: The comments you moved to chat! After I edited the question.

Comment: Steve: the comment I left, which is part of the question closing process, refers to the _opening sentence_ (amongst others), in your question. Comments to answers have no bearing on improving the _question_. These are separate issues. I think there's a fundamental misunderstanding about how Stack Exchange works. Let's continue this in the [chat room I created for you and I](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135930/room-for-scottbb-and-steve-bright) (others can also see and comment on it).

Answer (score 2):

An ND does not *increase* the recorded DR... it only shifts the scene brightness that is recorded to fill the recordable DR.

An ND can *decrease* the recorded DR if you use a higher ISO to offset some of the reduction in light. Or if you use an ND when the DR of the scene does not exceed the capability of the sensor (but why do that?).

The maximum dynamic range a sensor is capable of recording is dependent on using the lowest ISO, and exposing at least some photosites to full well capacity. This occurs whether an ND filter is used or not.
E.g. if you use a 2 stop ND and increase the exposure time by 4x (2 stops), in order to smooth water and record cloud blur, the recorded DR is not affected.

Similarly the contrast is not reduced in terms of the min/max recordable either; it is not reduced any more than any other form of underexposure would cause. However, if you use a *graduated ND* instead, to affect only the brightest areas of the scene, then you affect the DR/contrast variably.

Comment: Simply. Less DR is recorded according to the histogram.

Comment: @SteveBright, I've added a bit to my answer if that helps...

Comment: Take 2 snaps with and without ND. Adjust the exposure triangle any of 3 settings so the center of the histogram is the same. The range of light value is very much compressed. Regardless of the ISO chosen. Try it yourself. See Ross’s comment below.

Comment: @SteveBright:  it shouldn't be.  If you use a 2 stop ND and extend the exposure by a factor 4 you should get the same image and same histogram if the subject is static.

Comment: Yet it is! I will try next with an expensive filter.

Comment: See the last paragraph of Ross’s answer.

Comment: @SteveBright, it is difficult to say exactly all of the ways a very poor filter (or any other interference) could possibly impact the results. However, if you use a higher ISO you do reduce the DR... it is a linear response; one stop higher ISO means ~ one stop less exposure (light collected) which means ~ one stop less recorded DR (loss of highlights).

Comment: To be clear changing the iso one step even from 6400 to 12800, does not change the DR by one step. It is much less than one. From 100 to 200 barely at all. Even with a fixed iso, adding an ND decreases the range displayed on the histogram. Allowing for potentially more DR. Roughly one step for ND8.

Comment: "An ND does not increase the recorded DR..." You're reading something into the question that doesn't seem to be there. The question asks if a filter allows the camera to capture a higher dynamic range scene that the camera can otherwise record. It's asking if the DR of the light from a high DR scene before entering the camera is reduced to the camera's capacity, not if the camera's capacity is increased by the filter.

Comment: Exactly thanks for helping Michael.

Comment: @SteveBright, exactly how much DR ISO increase looses varies a bit by camera make model (how they report/rate ISO), and a bit more if you are measuring engineering DR vs *photographically useful DR* (signal visually discernible from noise). But it *is* very linear; this is the latest Nikon Z9: https://www.photonstophotos.net/Charts/PDR.htm#Nikon%20Z%209

Comment: @MichaelC, the second sentence asks about increasing the potential DR with an ND... which it cannot do.

Comment: I looked up my camera in your link above. As I said before the DR change going from 6400 to 12800 is less than one step. The other DR is much less than one. Going from 100 to 200 is smaller. Forget about iso.

Comment: The Potential DR increases when you insert an ND, and open the aperture. Try it. The histogram is compressed.

Answer (score 0):

An ideal ND filter just reduces the amount of light reaching the sensor evenly across the frame.  It does not change the contrast as the ratio of the brightest spot in your frame to the darkest spot in the frame will not change.  It does not change the dynamic range of your photograph.  It just takes a wider aperture or longer exposure to accumulate the light for a proper exposure.  This can be valuable if you want to limit the depth of field or induce some motion blur.

In one sense you can simulate the effect in post.  You can simulate an ND2 filter by sliding the exposure slider to -2 stops.  This will cut the amount of light in each pixel by a factor of 4.  Unfortunately, your photo is no longer properly exposed and you have lost two bits of brightness resolution.  When you have a real filter you extend the exposure by a factor 4 or open the lens by 2 stops to compensate and you get a properly exposed photo.

A high quality ND filter will approximate this better than a low quality one.  A low quality one may scatter light, which can reduce contrast by filling in the dark spots from the bright spots.  It may also reflect light off the surfaces, causing flare.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135929/discussion-on-answer-by-ross-millikan-do-nd-filters-affect-contrast-and-dynamic).